# Reading headers and time in a matrix

Tags: matlab, octave, text-parsing

I am trying to read files from a .txt file into a matrix. My problem is with the header and time. I read the header with the [`fgetl`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fgetl.html) function and the numbers with the [`dlmread`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dlmread.html) function skipping the top row. The format of my text file is:

```
time;col1;col2;col3;col4;col5;...
13:27:15.3167892;6.546785;5.456778;4.5561345435;....
................................
```

I tried using `importdata` and `datenum` but the problem is with the decimal places. How can I solve this?

I would like the output to be like this

```
Time               col1        col2       col3         
13:27:15.3167892   6.546785    5.456778   4.5561345435
```

Here is the code I am using, but it is unable to read the timestamps.

```
A = importdata(filename, ';', 1);
tm = datenum(A.textdata(2:end,1), 'HH:MM:SS');
data = A.data;
```

Answer (score 0):

If the number of columns is not known in advance, you can parse the header line first:

```
fid = fopen('input.txt');
cols = numel(regexp(fgetl(fid), ';', 'split'));
```

As for parsing the data, it seems best to use [`textscan`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html) here, making use of the number of columns to construct the correct format string. Also, it is probably better to keep the timestamp as a string and not as a numerical value:

```
fmt = ['%s ', repmat('%f', 1, cols - 1)];
C = textscan(fid, fmt, 'Delimiter', ';', 'CollectOutput', true);
T = vertcat(C{1}{:});  %// Extract timestamps
A = C{2};              %// Extract data values
```

And of course, don't forget to close the input file:

```
fclose(fid);
```

This leaves you with the timestamps stored in the string array (*i.e* `char` matrix) `T`, and the reset of the values data in the matrix `A`.

I'm not sure what you want to do with the timestamps, but you can manipulate `T` as you see fit, *e.g*:

```
vals = datenum(T)
```

**P.S.**
If you want to ignore the digits after decimal point, you can use the following format string instead:

```
fmt = ['%[^.].%*s ', repmat('%f', 1, cols - 1)];
```

Alternatively, if you want to keep only the first (most significant) three digits after the decimal point, you can use this:

```
fmt = ['%12s%*s ', repmat('%f', 1, cols - 1)];
```

**Octave**
Octave's `regexp` doesn't recognize the `'tokens'` option, and `'CollectOutput'` is not supported as well, so here's an alternative:

```
fid = fopen('input.txt');
cols = numel(regexp(fgetl(fid), ';')) + 1;
fmt = ['%s', repmat('%f', 1, cols - 1)];
C = textscan(fid, fmt, 'Delimiter', ';');
T = vertcat(C{1}{:});  %// Extract timestamps
A = [C{2:end}];        %// Extract data values
fclose(fid);
```

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning it earlier, but the problem is the file does not only contain 4 columns but varying from the output file of a test. Normally it contains 31 columns.

Comment: @user3082696 Do you care just about the timestamps or do you want the rest of the columns to be read as well?

Comment: Yes, I would like the timestamps to appear in the matrix. I am able to read the rest of the columns with importdata or dlmread function without problem. The problem is i could not read the timestamps. As you can see the time is in this format hh:mm:ss.sssssss . 7 decimal places for seconds. The timestamp is important but not the decimal places.

Comment: @user3082696 So you do want the other columns or not? It'll be a waste reading the file twice; you can do it with `textscan` in one go. Also, do you want the ignore "decimal places" (milliseconds) or do you want to keep them, or just the 3 most significant digits after the decimal point? Just describe what you want in a clear fashion, or even better, edit your question and add an example of an input and how you want the output matrix to look like.

Comment: I edit my question to make it clearer. Yes I want the other columns. It is best if I could keep the decimal places. But if it is not doable then it can be ignored.

Comment: @user3082696 Everything can be done once you define your goal correctly. By the way, you didn't mention how you want the output to look like in case you had variable number of columns.

Comment: I would like the output to be like in a matrix.e.g more columns means more to the right side.

Comment: @user3082696 But a matrix requires all rows to be of the same length. What would you put in the matrix instead of "missing" values? Are `NaN` values sufficient?

Comment: Every row is a data and every column is then the value of the date(e.g  height, weight etc). So it means every column will be filled with a value. Sorry for not mentioning it clear enough but now I got what you mean.

Comment: @user3082696 So what you mean was that you have a fixed number of columns, only not known in advance?

Comment: @user3082696 sorry for the late response. Please review the revised answer.